# How can I check multiple value in Model enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I want to check status of instance if it has more than two values

This is some model to use Rails Enum

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:status1, :status2, :status3]
end
```

I can check just one status of instance to use rails enum like

```
Product.first.status1?
```

If I want to check multiple statuses like this

```
Product.first.status1? || Product.first.status2?
```

How can I check enum values something like

```
Product.first.status?(:status1, :status2)`# this does not work
```

Does any method exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer to it is :

```
[:status1, :status2].include?(Product.first.status)
```

Answer (score 2):

alternative

```
(Product.first.status).in?[:status1, :status2]
```

but `include?` is faster